# Storing large dataframes on the go

Tags: python, pandas, cython

I'm trying to store large CSV files in python, but I am running out of RAM memory before being able to make a call to `to_csv`.

My code looks like:

```
v = []
v2 = []
...

for i in object:
    v.append(i.X)
    v2.append(i.Y)
    ...

db = {'V': v,
      'V2': v2,
      ...
     }

df = pandas.DataFrame(db, columns=['V','V2',...])
df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

However, the vectors `v`, `v2` and so on are extremely large (well above 100,000,000 in length).

I assume that there must be a way to create a dataframe "on the go", and append results to an output file, possibly without needing these vectors as intermediates. How would one do this on python/Cython? Thank you

**EDIT**

I have reached to this "solution", where no intermediates are generated, and the expected output is produced, without storing permanent large vectors.

I still feel that this is not an optimum solution, so I am not posting it as an answer, in the hope that someone comes with a better approach. Possible one with less I/O operations as this one.

```
count = 0
for i in object:
    df = pandas.DataFrame({'V': [i.X], 'V2': [i.Y], ...})
    if count==0:
        df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        count = 1
    else:
        df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: Looks like you want a real database...

Comment: I was thinking on the CSV mainly because this file will be latter processed in R and so it seems a convenient format. What database format could I check to try improving the performance here?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot tell without much more context (way more than I'm willing to learn actually xD) - and the point was to avoid loading 100,000,000 items in memory at once, it doesn't mean you can't create a CSV file for later processing (you don't need to load all your data at once to create a csv file).

Comment: Assuming that the numpy arrays or something like that you could probably do this in chunks instead of looping over each element individually.

Comment: Yes, in the end an intermediate solution is what is providing the best performance

Comment: A possibility would be to write a HDF5 File (h5py) and than read it with https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/rhdf5/inst/doc/rhdf5.html A float64 array with size 100,000,000 is only 800MB, which can be easily read or written to a binary file.

Comment: Another method would be to write a numpy-array to disk (np.save("Filename",arr)) and read it in R using http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.cnpy.html